# How does dismissing a presented UIViewController work?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Apple's View Controller Programming Guide for iOS [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW10):

> To dismiss a presented view controller, call the dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: method of the presenting view controller. You can also call this method on the presented view controller itself. When you call the method on the presented view controller, UIKit automatically forwards the request to the presenting view controller.

This is verified by the UIViewController [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss):

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal.

However this behavior seems ambiguous to me. What if a UIViewController is both *presented* and *presenting*? If you call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` on it, will it pass the call to its [`presentingViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) which will dismiss it, or will it dismiss its [`presentedViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621407-presentedviewcontroller)?

For example, suppose I have a `UIViewController` `vc1`, which creates and presents a `UIViewController` `vc2`, which then creates and presents `vc3`. So `vc1` has `vc2` as its `presentedViewController`, `vc2` has `vc1` as its `presentingViewController` and `vc3` as its `presentedViewController`, and `vc3` has `vc2` as its `presentedViewController`. Then `dismiss(animated:completion:)` is called on `vc2`. Which is dismissed, `vc2` or `vc3`? If `vc2` is dismissed, what happens to `vc3`?

Comment: Try it. See what happens. That's the best way to learn.